# Calling member function from another member function's implementation

Tags: c++, class, vector, member-functions

So I'm defining a class `sqmatrix` of square matrices for fun and learning, and I've successfully defined a function `submat` that outputs a submatrix of the object constructed in a certain way:

```
sqmatrix sqmatrix::submat (unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
{ /* code */   return smat;    }
```

Now I want to define another function that takes the submatrix constructed by `submat` and outputs, say, the matrix where all elements have been multiplied by `42`. To do so, I wrote

```
sqmatrix sqmatrix::cofact (unsigned int srow, unsigned int scol)
{
   sqmatrix cfac = 42 * m_mat.submat(srow, scol);
   return cfac;
}
```

where I'd previously overloaded `*` to work with my objects, and `m_mat` has been declared in the header of the class as a `vector` of `vector`s containing `long long int`s. However, this did not compile, so I went for member function pointers and wrote:

```
sqmatrix sqmatrix::cofact (unsigned int srow, unsigned int scol)
{
   sqmatrix (sqmatrix::*point)(unsigned int, unsigned int);
   point = &sqmatrix::submat;
   sqmatrix cfac = 42 * (m_mat.*point)(srow, scol);
   return cfac;
}
```

However, this does not compile either. Here are the relevant lines in the header file:

```
private:
 // ...
 std::vector< std::vector<long long int> > m_mat;
public:
 // ...
 sqmatrix submat(unsigned int row, unsigned int col);
 sqmatrix cofact(unsigned int srow, unsigned int scol);
```

Compiler says:

> Error: pointer to member type `sqmatrix (sqmatrix::)(unsigned int,unsigned int)` incompatible with object type `std::vector< std::vector<long long int> >`

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I think your problem is that you are attempting to call submat() on an instance of std::vector (m_mat)..
submat() is a member function of sqmatrix

Comment: `m_mat` is a `vector` of `vector`s. `vector`s do not have a `submat` methods and cannot invoke `sqmatrix` method pointers..

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your pointer member voodoo seems equivalent to `m_mat.submat(srow, scol)`, which clearly won't work because `m_mat` does not have this method, it's not a `sqmatrix`. Pointer to a member won't magically let you call methods from one type on another type, what would it even suppose to mean?

Comment: So how do I invoke the `submat` on the object I'm applying `cofact` to? To construct the output of `cofact` I need to first send the object into `submat` and then do something to the resulting matrix...

Comment: It sounds like you need a `submat` constructor that takes a vector of vectors and creates the equivalent `submat`. Or maybe the vector of vectors should be a member variable of `submat`.

Comment: The object you are applying `cofact` to is `*this`, not `m_mat`. Maybe you should call `submat` on `this`. I am not sure, your design is weird. It's hard to read intentions.

Comment: @luk32 Thank you, that works. I just got confused because in defining other member functions such as `submat` I was able to reference `m_mat` directly by using `vector` methods (e.g. `m_mat[i][j]`), so I assumed it would be natural to do just that in this situation. I was not aware of `this` or `*this`, for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmm. I think you're wanting:

```
sqmatrix sqmatrix::cofact (unsigned int srow, unsigned int scol)
{
   sqmatrix cfac = 42 * submat(srow, scol);
   return cfac;
}
```

No idea what kind of matrix operation you're actually trying to do, but if you're trying to take the submatrix of `this` and then multiply it by a constant 42, then you just need to call `submat(srow, scol)`.

The way you've written it, you're trying to call a member function of a vector, instead of a member function of your class which contains the vector.

C++ allows you to also call `this->submat(srow, scol)` which may make it more clear what you're actually doing, but most of the time you see people call member functions with no reference to `this`, as its perfectly valid C++ and also shorter.

Comment: Thank you. As I said, when I posted I was not aware of `this`. Your solution has helped me